# Twitter connect example

Tags: android, twitter, android-asynctask, android-twitter

I wanted to learn twitter connect example. For that i just downloaded a sample app from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/). I just tried to run that app. When I run this app on Android 2.3.3, it is working fine but when I run it on android 4.1.2, it's giving an error `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. In that code, the author has used `AsynTask` background thread to perform network operations but still this error exists. Now I am confused, where is the error coming from. Please help.

Comment: if there is any reference to the main thread from background process then too the prob apears as it blocks the main thread post your code so others can understand where the prob is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Solution of this Problem.

1) Don't write network call in Main `UIThread`, Use `Async` Task for that.

2) Write below code into your `MainActivity` file after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

And below import statement into your java file.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

Comment: i even tried this way. but wen i paste this code, i will get an error, assisting(Crrl+1) me to create a class by name StrictMode rather than to import android.os.StrictMode;

Comment: @suresh This solution is working for me and first import above statement in your main java file and then build your project and check, it will solve your problem.

Comment: I am sorry. if i import this, this line(import android.os.StrictMode;) this line itself is a showing an error. Actualy i got to know to use StrictMode from many of the sites. but am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: "The import android.os.StrictMode cannot be resolved" is the error i am getting after import.

Comment: @suresh see full code here and check what happened http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android.html

Comment: I am also trying this tutorial and some more twitter android integration tutorials and result is same NOT SUCCEED. After your answer now I have a working sample project..,. THANKS A LOT..,,

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked by removing the  `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` line in the Android Manifest file. Initially i am also got the issue **NetworkOnMainThreadException"** and have removed the line which i have mentioned above and have checked it . I am checked in 4.0.2 Please check it in 4.1.2

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ya i checked it now. but still the problem retains.

Comment: i have posted the tweet also it got posted in 4.0.2 .. but i am not updated the version 4.1 so i am unable to test it... whats the  issue right now you are getting .

Comment: I pasted the StrictMode code posted by IGP, but wen i paste this code, i will get an error, assisting(Crrl+1) me to create a class by name StrictMode rather than to import android.os.StrictMode

Comment: hi .. without strict mode why don't you tried . And my small advice you want to post the twit.. that too not continue-sly in background mode , if will post twit when user want thats it rigt

Comment: my app itself is not working,(with or without StrictMode).I treid to run it both on emulator(android 4.1.2 and Nexus having 4.2). the app just crashes after start.

Comment: Just now i have tested in the 4.1 Emulator it worked and posted the tweet. and have checked it in twitter site also. its works fine... have tested 4.0.3 Android Tablet . worked fine.. i am not changed any line  the code which you have provided. just i have pasted my consumer and secret key . and removed one line in manifest . thats it ...