# Update old android project

Tags: android, user-interface, styles, project

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and I can make it work just fine, but when I try to update the UI to fit the new Holo.Light in android 4.2 the app crashes at launch, and I don't know why.

I have been searching for a way to update the UI but I could not get it to work.

I wonder if anybody could help me? tell me how? Give me a link that you know would work?
or even do it yourself?

i get this error log:

```
11-20 09:50:39.523: I/dalvikvm(1460): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-20 09:50:39.682: I/dalvikvm(1460): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-20 09:50:39.892: I/dalvikvm(1460): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-20 09:50:40.003: I/dalvikvm(1460): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-20 09:50:40.102: D/AndroidRuntime(1460): Shutting down VM
11-20 09:50:40.102: W/dalvikvm(1460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.jsonparsing/com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:53)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-20 09:50:40.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     ... 11 more
11-20 09:50:40.392: I/dalvikvm(1460): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-20 09:50:40.412: I/dalvikvm(1460): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-20 09:50:40.791: I/dalvikvm(1460): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-20 09:50:40.962: I/dalvikvm(1460): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: And we wont know why unless your post logcat trace

Comment: sure, here it is:
http://i.imgur.com/drBOV.png

Comment: @Magnus: It would be better if you would edit your question and include the error text instead of attaching a screen shot that is gone in some weeks.

Comment: @Robert thank you, i have done it now

Comment: Are your permissions set right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Solution of this Problem.

1) Don't write network call in Main UIThread, Use Async Task for that.

2) Write below code into your MainActivity file after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

And below import statement into your java file.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

and see below link for more information.

[Twitter connect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448468/twitter-connect-example/13448512#13448512)

Comment: @MagnusJensen Welcome Magnus.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. All this is doing is preventing the issue from being reported and does not alter the fact that you are making network calls on the UI thread may result in ANRs. You would be much better off following point 1 than point 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a network call on the main thread. This is not allowed on Android 4.2, and is a really bad idea on earlier versions which do permit this. I have blogged about various mechanisms for moving network and other heavy calls off the main thread at http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/833.

Without seeing your code, I cannot begin to suggest which approach is the right one for you to use, but hopefully the information in my articles will help you in deciding upon the correct approach.